# Windows shares: Different folders for different users?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

What is working right now is:

On the server I have the folders

```
\some\folder\share\alices-folder
\some\folder\share\bobs-folder
```

and the users `alice` and `bob`. The folder `\some\folder\share` is shared.

On the Windows client machine I have the local accounts `alice` and `bob`. When they connect to the server, they can only see the content of the `\some\folder\share` folder. That is, they see the folders `alices-folder` and `bobs-folder`, but they cannot access parent folders like `\some\folder` or `\some`.

---

Now, I would like to have a different folder structure (for reasons not of interest right now):

```
\other\folder\users\alice\share
\other\folder\users\bob\share
```

and when `alice` connects to the server, she should only see the content of the folder `\other\folder\users\alice\share` and not be able to access parent folders like `\other\folder\users\alice` or `\other\folder\users`.

And of course also when `bob` connects to the server from the same client machine the same should apply to him, so again he should only see the content of the folder `\other\folder\users\bob\share` and not be able to access parent folders like `\other\folder\users\bob` or `\other\folder\users`.

---

Is this possible - without giving the server different alias-names?

---

**Update**

Sorry that I forgot to write that I already know about restricting access with permissions. So, when I wrote what is working already, I do already restrict access as needed.

But I still wanted to know if what I wanted to get is possible by 'simple' means - a Distributed File System I would not call simple. ;-)

Comment: If you have a domain controller, this is very easy to setup automatically using group policies, to ensure that the users only see their share.

Comment: You do not need a DFS for this. Just a group policy with shares mapped and you can even put the username in there, so it is just one policy that applies to all users.

Comment: @LPChip So, if I understand you correctly, the simplest way to do this is with a domain controller and there is no way to do it without a domain controller? If yes and you post this as an answer, I will accept this as the solution.

Comment: No, it is possible without a domain controller, but its much more work. A domain controller can push this out from one place.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for clarification! I still would like you to write all you said here as an answer, so I could accept it as the solution. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run an Active Directory on a server, the easiest would be to use group policies to manage network shares.

This gives you the ability to link a drive letter to a folder that contains the username, and the user won't notice that it is different.

In addition, new users will automatically get the network drive without requiring setting up the shares once more.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like you're going about this the wrong way. Consider reading [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754178(v=ws.11)) it has details about the interaction of share and NTFS permissions.

Generally it shouldn't be much of a problem of just having read permissions for everyone on the share and use the NTFS permissions to limit access. If it's an issue that users see other users folders consider looking into [access based enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/enable-access-based-enumeration-on-a-namespace) but that would mean you'd have to run a DFS from what I know.

With the options you have presented you likely would need to create individual shares for alice and bob (so share_bob, share_alice) and mount them for the individual user.

Comment: Many apologies for inflicting unnecessary work, but see my update.

Comment: No need to apologize. You updated your question and refined it. I'll leave the answer up anyway. Have a nice day @f.d.g.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather in your question, this is an extremely simple file sharing scenario.

Of course, I am assuming that when you write `\other\folder\users\alice\share` or other such paths that start with a `\`, these folders are at the root of a drive like `D:` but you don't want to disclose the drive letter. If not, just replace `D:` in my answer with anything correct for your case.

Please follow these steps:

1. Log in to the server (either via the console or Remote Desktop)
2. Open File Explorer. (Prior to Windows Server 2012, it is called Windows Explorer.)
3. Navigate to 'D:\other\folder\users\alice`
4. Right-click on `share` and select "Properties". (Or just select `share` and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> combination.) The "share Properties" dialog box would open.
5. Locate the "Sharing" tab. (This step and the following step might be slightly different for old versions of Windows Server.)
6. Click on the "Advanced Sharing" button, so that the "Advanced Sharing" dialog box opens.
7. Put a checkmark in the "Share this folder" box.
8. In the "Share name" field, type "For Alice" (or whatever you like, minding the naming rules).
9. Click on the Permissions button.
10. In the next dialog box, remove all users in the list using the Remove button and add Alice using the Add... button. Then, select Alice and put check mark in the check box in front of "Full Control" and under "Allow". Close the dialog box by pressing OK.
11. Close the "Advanced Sharing" dialog box by pressing OK. You are now back at the "share Properties" dialog box.
12. Navigate to the Security tab and make sure NTFS permissions are granted in a way to permit Alice access. One can argue that this step is so complex that you need two or three chapters of a Windows Server book for it. I'd say yes, but chances are you don't have to do anything here.
13. Click OK to close the "share Properties" dialog box.
14. Test what you did so far. If you navigate to `\\servername` (or whatever is the name of your server) in File Explorer, you must be able to see a new `For Alice` share, which has the icon of a folder. Only Alice must be able to open it.
15. Repeat these steps for Bob.

There are several other ways of accomplishing all this:

- Using the Computer Management snap-in of Microsoft Management Console
- Using the Manage My Server app
- Using PowerShell (my favorite, but unavailable in the older versions)
- Using the now-outdated and deprecated Command Prompt!

But you didn't specify a Windows version, so I wrote the GUI solution instead.

Comment: Many apologies for inflicting unnecessary work, but see my update.

Comment: No need for apologies. Still, I don't see how your update would impact my answer. The way I see it, if you follow these instructions, you get exactly what you asked ...  unless... what I am reading isn't what you intended to communicate? You'd be surprised to know how often this happens: Someone asks a question, not realizing that only people in his immediate vicinity understand him/her as he/she intends. SuperUser members comes from all around the globe.

Comment: Oh, I see LPChip has understood your meaning... I am happy for you.  Good luck.